# Get content of an Uploaded File and place content into a table with existing format

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I have this code here that handles the upload for my form, but i want to take it a step further and grab the content of the uploaded file (.doc, docx, .txt) and place the content line by line into a table with the existing format or just echo it out on the page like a preview.

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}

// store file content as a string in $str
$str = file_get_contents($_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
echo $str;

?>
```

Best,
Antone

Comment: This is the message i get after uploading. "Test.txt upload is complete
Warning: file_get_contents(Test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/toneking1989/everestt.co/action.php on line 18"

Comment: Which OS you are using ?

Comment: windows 7. The file uploads fine. I just want to beable to grab the contents of that file and place it into a table or echo it out on the web page.

Comment: That specifically didnt work but it got me thinking so i changed $str = file_get_content("uplaods/$filename"); and its grabbing it from my upload dir. I may have not been using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] right though, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open and read the file line by line once it is in it's destination, like so:

```
<?php
    $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
    if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
        echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
        exit();
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){
        echo "$fileName upload is complete";

        $handle = fopen("uploads/$fileName", "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                // process the line read.
            }

            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            // error opening the file.
        }
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
    }

    // store file content as a string in $str
    $str = file_get_contents($_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
    echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Getting an error on that second from last line.  For some reason its looking in this directory, /home/toneking1989/everestt.co/action.php ? and not in the uploads dir on my webserver. No issues uploading to though. here is the ERROR Warning: file_get_contents(Test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/toneking1989/everestt.co/action.php on line 29

Comment: It is probably an issue with the pathing, PHP requires full path vs relative path. So you can usually use something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'uploads/';` to ensure you are always writing and reading to/from the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. I normally use this code. See, if you want to know the extension. Then, one function i gave it to you, write there all possible extension. There is a way to get extension, you can use that way also.. but, this is the way, how i use to upload a file. Hope i understood your question.

```
function GetPropertyImageExtension($imagetype)
{
   if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
   switch($imagetype)
   {
      case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';

      case 'image/gif': return '.gif';

      case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';

      case 'image/png': return '.png';

      default: return false;

   }
}
if (!empty($_FILES['CustomImage']["name"]))
{   
   $file_name=$_FILES['CustomImage']["name"];
   $temp_name=$_FILES['CustomImage']["tmp_name"];
   $imgtype=$_FILES['CustomImage']["type"];
   $ext= GetPropertyImageExtension($imgtype);
   $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;

   $target_path = "../Custom Cake Images/".$imagename;
   $Rtarget_path = "Custom Cake Images/".$imagename;
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CustomImage']['tmp_name'], $Rtarget_path ))
   {
      [..SQL Query..]
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @JAL This code i'm using since 1 year. So, this code helped me in each way. Now, it's USER view.. how they use.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will acutaly use this in another way but madness gave me the answer i needed for right now. best antone